Как получить потомков с использованием xpath?
Нужно получить потомка для каждого предка, но получаю только потомка первого предка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?
const parent_xpath = '//div[@class="parent-class-name"]'
let parent_elems = document.evaluate(parent_xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

for (let i = 0; i < parent_elems.snapshotLength; i++) {
    let parent_elem = parent_elems.snapshotItem(i)

    const child_xpath = '//div[@class="child-class-name"]'
    let child_elem = document.evaluate(child_xpath, parent_elem, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

    console.log(child_elem)
}

